# Custom ASP.NET Membership controls added via button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I customise ASP.NET DB Membership Providers?

In my ASP.NET database I added two columns to Membership table: Age and Address.

In the Register.aspx page there are built-in fields such as User Name, E-Mail, Password, Confirm Password.

I want to add age and address, and when the user clicks Create User button, data entered in age and address will be stored in the ASP.NET DB.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add new field to your page then, you have to create your own `RegistrationForm` programatically.

Drag `textboxes` in your design view, and in your code behind file write this,

```
protected void CreateUser_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipCreateStatus result;
        try
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                Membership.CreateUser(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, true, out result);

                switch (result)
                {
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                        Response.Write("Email ID is already exist");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateProviderUserKey:
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                        Response.Write("UserName is already Exists !");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                        Response.Write("Not a Valid Email ID");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                        Response.Write("Atleast 6 Charcters are required for Password");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidProviderUserKey:
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                        Response.Write("Fail to Register ");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                        Response.Write("Successfulley Registered");
                        break;
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                        Response.Write("Fail to Register, ");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Response.Write(err.Message);
        }
    }
```

And tell me whether it works for you or not...

Comment: Thanks v.much Eng\ Krunal, It works Successfully,
But CreateUser() Method doesnot have the columns that i have added in Membership Table such as Age and Address Columns ??!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser.aspx

Comment: chk this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467724/how-to-add-a-parameter-to-membership-createuser