# How to Add a Parameter to Membership.CreateUser()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

```
CreateUser (string username, string password, string email,
string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved,
object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status );


Membership.CreateUser (TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, 
TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, true, out result);
```

Can i override `CreateUser()` Function to add extra parameters as age and address and store these data into the corresponing Columns that i added in Membership Table in ASPNETDB

Comment: If these methods were static you cant override those functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a subclass of the membership provider you use and provide an additional `CreateUser` method that takes the parameters you require to create the user.

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public MembershipUser CreateUser(/* your custom arguments*/)
    {

    }
}
```

Create an extension method to invoke your method.

```
public static MembershipUser CreateUser(this Membership membership, /* your custom arguments*/)
{
       ((MyMembershipProvider)membership.Provider).CreateUser(/* your custom arguments*/);
}
```

Then you can use it as an orverload of the `CreateUser` method.

```
Membership.CreateUser(/* your custom arguments*/);
```

Comment: // For Example i need this signature, where is the code behind to do this :)
public MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, 
            string confirmpassword , string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer,
            string age, string address, string deptid,
            bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {

        }

Comment: Eranga, is this necessary to implement the function from scratch ??!!

Comment: @SherifEzzat That is the proper way of doing it. Framework does not provide a mechanism to include custom arguments of your choice. So you need to implement it yourself. Closely following the framework structure will make your code more discoverable, readable and maintainable.

Comment: Eranga, Thanks for your great effort, i will try to do it

Answer (score 1):

In reference to Eranga's suggestion:

This will not work, static types cannot be used as parameters. As far as I know you cannot override the `CreateUser` method without writing your own custom provider, then creating a public CreateUser method with your own parameters, then casting the provider to call your method like so:

```
((MyMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).CreateUser(/* my parameters */)
```